# How to remove the divider lines of an ExpansionTile when expanded in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an ExpansionTile within my Drawer widget. When I expand this item, it automatically adds a divider line above and below. I want these divider lines permanently.

So I'd either like to know how to show the ExpansionTile's divider lines always (expanded and unexpanded), or I can add my own divider lines and tell the ExpansionTile to never show divider lines.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

you can hide divider lines by wrapping the ExpansionTile widget in Theme Widget,

your code will look like this after you add Theme widget

```
Theme(
     data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
     child:ExpansionTile(
         title:...,
         children:[],
     ),
),
```

check this [Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67459)

Comment: How do you always show the divider lines, which was included in the question?

Comment: @RJB is a bug that show horizontal lines on top and bottom of your ExpansionTile once is opened....it was luckily resolved by Dasunx answer =).

Comment: Ugly, but works like a charm. The aesthetic results outweigh the code ugliness :)

Comment: I'm wonder why `dividerTheme: DividerThemeData( color: Colors.transparent,)` did not work.

Answer (score 27):

Another option is that instead of wrapping the `ExpansionTile` widget with Theme, you can pass the shape directly to `ExpansionTile` as follows:

```dart
ExpansionTile(
  // ...
  shape: Border(),
)
```

Comment: This is the only solution that fixes the annoying border line.

Comment: It works for when set `collapsedShape: Border(),` inside `ExpansionTileThemeData`

Comment: This should be marked as the right solution!
The other solution where the divider color is set to transparent doesn't remove the divider, and it still takes up space and moves the expansion tile a tiny bit when expanding.

Answer (score 6):

@RJB, I had the same issue, I resolved wrapping the ExpansionTile with a column, like this:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(
         'My title',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          _showContent
              ? Icons.expand_less_rounded
              : Icons.expand_more_rounded,
        ),
        onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
          setState(() => _showContent = expanded);
        },
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('My content'),
        ],
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.amber,
        thickness: 1,
        height: 0,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I know it isn't pretty, but I could't find an Expansion component that I could personalize every aspect of its appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that while the solution

```
ExpansionTile(
  // ...
  shape: Border(),
)
```

succeeds in removing the borders, it leads to the title widget (and icons) to wiggle/slightly move upwards on expanding. This is because the layout is designed with the expectation that a border with minimal height is added in the expanded stage above the title widget (which we remove with the approach above). This does not happen in the other solution:

```
Theme(
 data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
 child:ExpansionTile(
     title:...,
     children:[],
 ),
 ),
```