# How can I remove this gray line from ExpansionTile? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

How can I remove this gray line from ExpansionTile in flutter?

[image]

The Code

```
ExpansionTile(
          title: Text(
            "Title",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'data'
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the divider lines of an ExpansionTile when expanded in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667990/how-to-remove-the-divider-lines-of-an-expansiontile-when-expanded-in-flutter)

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this applying a transparent color to the `dividerColor` in the `ThemeData` in your `MaterialApp` definition.

```
MaterialApp(
   title: 'Your Flutter App',
   theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
```

Of course you can make your own implementation of a custom widget.

Answer (score 4):

you can wrap the widget with Material Theme like this :

```
Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              title: Text(
                "Title",
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('data'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```